# Bad/illegal format or missing url in windows bash

Tags: windows, curl

In bash I gave the following code:

```
file_path =“/D:/test/a.txt/“
Local_path = “/D:/test/b.txt/“

Curl -Q “-rename $file_path” -k $file_path -O $local_path
```

I got the below error:

> Curl(3) url using bad/illegal format or missing url
> -O not found

Comment: I doubt something wrong in the path I provided

Answer (score 1):

`-rename`  must be an argument on its own.

Assuming that your `Curl` is just an alias for `curl`, you could write

```
Curl -rename "$file_path" -k "$file_path" -O "$local_path"
```